# Do you need a gateway configured when using Azure Synapse Analytics

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource, azure-synapse

I am trying to understand the impact of migrating current on premise sql data warehouse to Azure synapse analytics from a powerBI perspective.

Azure synapse studio allows you to create a linked service which enables you to create/modify and publish powerbi reports to powerbi service.

All reports are using Import Mode connection.

Once the PowerBI report is published, how are the PowerBI datasets refreshed?
Do you need to set up a gateway on a azure VM? If so, is this the only option?

Comment: If importing the data into Power BI, the data is refreshed in the Power BI Service setting for the dataset. You can set a timed schedule there

Answer (score 0):

In case if the network setting of the Synapse workspace (in case if suing Synapse workspace) or SQL server(in case formerly Azure SQL DW) has the property enabled for 'Allow Azure services and resources to access this workspace/resource '
Then powerbi can directly access the database without the need of a gateway.

In case if the property is disabled, then you would need to set up a gateway on a VM, whitelist the IP of that VM in the firewall rule and use it to refresh the PowerBI.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on whether you're using Power BI Desktop or the Enterprise/workspace.

Desktop connections can be allowed through the Synapse firewall like direct IP address.

Workspaces can access Synapse if:

- `"Allow Azure services and resources to access this workspace/resource"` under your Firewall tab of your Synapse is enabled. OR
- You have a gateway.

Or you can link the Power BI and Synapse via Syanapse workspace directly as [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/quickstart-power-bi).

Comment: Thanks Kashyap. Most likely we will be using Enterprise/Workspace. So if you link PowerBI and Synapse workspace directly, you do not need a gateway? and you also do not need to "Allow Azure services and resources to access this workspace/resource" under firewall?

Comment: Never used Synapse Workspace (we use Dedicated SQL Pools) so can't say. But based on the description in the link it looks like it's not needed. Though it is linking workspace to an existing Power BI workspace.